# Please remove "please review it" requests when questions have been deleted

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-questions

In the top left area of my SO account I could see 1 message asking to *"please review it"*, referring to an edit on a question I made on SE.  Meanwhile that question had been deleted.

Opening a link to any SE site from Google to find a non-existing page is already something we're seeing all too often (and all too often complained about in blogs / on hackernews / etc.) so it would be nice if in addition to that issue such broken links wouldn't appear in the notification made to users.

*P.S: I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one to have been hit by this issue seen the sheer number of questions that are getting deleted on a hourly basis.*