# Please remove deleted answers from review queue

Tags: feature-request

This is related to [Please remove "please review it" requests when questions have been deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137840/please-remove-please-review-it-requests-when-questions-have-been-deleted) but the problem I often see isn't on deleted questions but that I'm asked to review a post which has been deleted.

For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729873/how-can-i-send-email-to-someones-facebook-com-address-without-it-landing-in-th) minitech deleted an answer (which was the thing to do) but I'm still asked to review it.

Comment: This wasn't refused, closed, nor downvoted to hell. Does it mean it might be on some TODO list ?